# Querying sub-collections of sub-collections in firebase using React JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database that is structured as such:

```
-users
|--username
  |--forms
    |--applicantInformation
    |--guardianInformation
    |--terms
```

Where "users" is the main collection, username is a document in "users", "forms" is a sub-collection of "username", and the "applicantInformation, guardianInformation, and terms" are all sub-collections of the forms sub-collection.

How do I access the applicantInformation, guardianInformation and terms?

I have tried using:

```
const db = firebase.firestore()

db.collectionGroup("forms")
      .collectionGroup("applicantInformation")
      .get()
      .then(snap => snap.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.data())));
```

```
 db.collectionGroup("forms")
      .get()
      .then(snap => {
        snap.forEach(doc =>
          doc
            .collection("applicantInformation")
            .get()
            .then(snap => snap.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.data())))
        );
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

```
db.collection("users")
      .get()
      .then(snap =>
        snap.forEach(doc => doc.collection("applicantInformation"))
      );
```

According to the documentation I should be able to do:

```
db.collectionGroup("applicantInformation").get()...
```

but this returns no values in the console.

I've searched this site and the documentation, and found problems similar, but nothing to do with sub-collections nested inside sub-collections. The problem is that I need to loop through each user and pull out each form's data for a table.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I should also point out that this is all done via web, no node is involved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I made a similar structure in my testing database, the method I used to read nested values was this:

```js
db.collection('users').doc('forms').collection('applicantInformation').get()
  .then((snap) => {
    snap.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
    });
  });
```

Here is a screenshot of my structure, hope it helps!

[image: Here is a screenshot of my structure]

Update:

If you need to get that specific nested subcollection you could try this:

```js
db.collection('users')
  .doc(username)
  .collection('forms')
  .doc('applicantInformation')
  .get()
  .then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
```

Comment: Will be sure to try this tomorrow. Thanks for the insight, really appreciate it. I’ll mark it as accepted assuming it all works but it looks like it will!

Comment: I should've specified that the users collection has users organized by name in it.

So there is a collection of users that I need to loop through, to pull each specific users forms.
`users --> username --> forms --> applicationInformation`
So, essentially I need to write something along the lines of:
`db.collection('users').doc('firstName, lastName').collection('forms').doc('applicantInformation').get()`
The problem is I just need to access every user's information on a loop so it all appears in the admin table that I'm creating in React.

Comment: I edited my initial post to clarify things a tad more.